# Mongodb Atlas connections are Maxing out. Instance M10 (350 Concurrent Connections)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

Mongodb Atlas with `M10 instance` is suppose to give `350 concurrent connections` which I am able to get it. But as soon as I start the server where I use mongoose for transactions, connections are getting maxed out and all the other requests are being in queue.

Options I am using for mongoose connect is:

```
const options = {
    reconnectTries: Number.MAX_VALUE,
    poolSize: 10,
    autoIndex: false
}
```

Unable to close connections after transactions are complete. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: 1) How do you know that the transactions are complete ? 2) Why did you reduce the pool size in the option? 3) How many concurrent connections does your application make ? 4) Have you tried opening a MongoDB Atlas support ticket ?

Comment: @Wan Bachtiar 
1) transactions are complete once I get response from the server. Which i am getting now.
2) I went through lot of posts before asking question here. They suggested to reduce the pool size. I don't know if i am correct.
3) I have the application running in just 50 devices, but Mongodb atlas is showing 350 concurrent connections.
4) I tried to ask then but didn't get proper answer for what i am looking for.
Any help would be great.

Comment: You mentioned 50 devices (applications), so how many active connections per application makes? If each makes 10 concurrent active connections, then that's already 500.

Comment: @WanBachtiar Please correct me if I'm wrong, Isn't it like after the transaction is complete connections are supposed to close. My Understanding is connections happen only when Application requests some data from that backend, as soon as the response is sent from the backend transaction is complete & connection is suppose to close. But that is not happening connection stays open doesn't let any other connections to happen. Please help me out with this. Thanks you.

Comment: What transaction are you referring to ? i.e. multi-document transactions in v4+. Every MongoClient instance has a built-in connection pool per server in your MongoDB topology. These pools open sockets on demand to support the number of concurrent MongoDB operations that your multi-threaded application requires. The size of each connection pool is capped at `maxPoolSize`. The MongoClient should be created once per process and reuse for all operations.